# Eclipse Kepler doesn't want to open java code in jsf on ctrl key

Tags: java, eclipse, jsf, el

I cannot manage to do it working.

In previous versions of eclipse there was no such problem. Erlier when I put mouse over EL expression and pressed CTRL key - EL expression was underlined, and when I clicked over it - it took me into java code.

Now: in Kepler - eclipse throw me an exception (in error log):

```
Message: Unhandled event loop exception
Plug-in: org.eclipse.ui

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.jst.jsf.designtime.internal.view.AbstractDTViewHandler.getWebContentPath(AbstractDTViewHandler.java:214)
    at org.eclipse.jst.jsf.designtime.internal.view.AbstractDTViewHandler.getViewId(AbstractDTViewHandler.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.jst.jsf.designtime.DTAppManagerUtil.getXMLViewDefnAdapter(DTAppManagerUtil.java:101)
    at org.eclipse.jst.jsf.designtime.DTAppManagerUtil.getXMLViewDefnAdapter(DTAppManagerUtil.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.jst.jsf.ui.internal.jspeditor.JSPSourceUtil.getELExpression(JSPSourceUtil.java:115)
    at org.eclipse.jst.jsf.ui.internal.jspeditor.JSPSourceUtil.findELRegion(JSPSourceUtil.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.jst.jsf.ui.internal.jspeditor.AbstractELHyperlinkDetector.detectHyperlinks(AbstractELHyperlinkDetector.java:66)
    at org.eclipse.jst.jsf.ui.internal.jspeditor.AbstractELHyperlinkDetector.detectHyperlinks(AbstractELHyperlinkDetector.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.HyperlinkDetectorRegistry$HyperlinkDetectorDelegate.detectHyperlinks(HyperlinkDetectorRegistry.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.hyperlink.HyperlinkManager.findHyperlinks(HyperlinkManager.java:289)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.hyperlink.HyperlinkManager.findHyperlinks(HyperlinkManager.java:261)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.hyperlink.HyperlinkManager.mouseMove(HyperlinkManager.java:469)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:212)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1057)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4170)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3759)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1113)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:997)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:611)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:567)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:181)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1450)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1426)
```

Please note that resolving el expressions in JSF - when I'm starting writting it works fine. 
Do you have any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, finally I managed to solve problem configuring Eclipse project facets.

I followed this tutorial: http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/how-to-make-eclipse-ide-supports-jsf-2-0/